# Broadcast can not receive package_removed event after registered staticly in Manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I know there are similar question in statckoverflow, but they just do NOT work for me.

Broadcast receiver(staticly registe via manifest.xml) can NOT receive package_remove event after installing on device (without running main activity)

But the receiver works if main activity is running.

To register broadcastreceiver staticly in AndroidManifest.xml as followings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.broadcastreceivertesting"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >
     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
             android:name="com.example.broadcastreceivertesting.MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastreceivertesting.PackageBroadcastReceiver" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                 <data android:scheme="package" />
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

     </application>
 </manifest>
```

PackageBroadcastReceiver as a receiver are like following:

```
public class PackageBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(action))
        {
            File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/zzz/yyy");
            if (file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
            }
            boolean createDir = new File("/storage/sdcard0/zzz/").mkdirs();
            Log.d("XXX", "XXXX createDir=" + createDir);
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this...

```
<intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
             <data android:scheme="package" />
```

to this...

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:value="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" /> 
            <scheme android:value="package" />
```

For more information, see this link on receiving package broadcast intents...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/aX5-fMbdPR8

Comment: it comes with error as "Multiple annotations found at this line: - Tag <scheme> missing required attribute scheme."

Comment: Try changing android:value="package" to android:scheme="package"